# Unable to resolve Exception: The parameters (number[]) don't match the method signature for SpreadsheetApp.Range.setValues

Tags: google-sheets

I know this is a frequent question as I've been trying to find an answer, but I'm struggling on how to convert my 1d array into a 2d array as seen in my code. When new rows are submitted when the script runs, i'm attempting to have the date fill out as well. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image: See here]

[image]

Comment: I changed my date var from this 

`function archivedate() {

 var sss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1ji3Q02uOyrDXyrl7LcghWLcLjz-CeSUgSCU7QD0BVEk'); 

 var ss = sss.getSheetByName('Allergen Planner'); 

var range = ss.getRange('R21:S34');
 
var data = range.getValues();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `.map()` function returns `rowData.push(new Date())`. The [Array.push()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) method does not return the modified *array* but the *length* of the array, which explains why `data` is a 1D array of numbers. Try this instead:

```
  const now = new Date();
  const data = range.getValues().map(row => row.concat(now));
```